# Office applications cannot download files from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

When i try to download and edit (check out) a file from our sharepoint server, the splashscreen for the appropriate office application opens and states that its "Downloading" the file (See picture; "hämtar" = "downloading" in swedish). This screen appears for about 5 minutes then it says that it cannot find the file or that it cannot connect to the server.

[image]

I have:

- Restarted my computer.
- Checked that no files are checked out.
- Checked that no files are in the office upload center que.
- Cleared upload center cache.
- Cleared sharepoint cache in appdata.

This issue started a few weeks ago but before that it was fine.
I can download files from my profile on other computers, so it got to be a local chache or something that is corrupt.

Any idea?